# Repeating Text Within a Word Document?

Tags: ms-office

Using OS X 10.6.8 and Word 2011 for Mac. I have developed a Word document template for a client which is used for surveys.  Each time the document is used, it has a different property address.  Is there a way of linking the address which appears in the main part of the text on the Front Page to the centre section of the header on the following pages so that you only have to type it in once?

Eg:

Front page says:

> 20 Feb 2013 Survey for Mr & Mrs Bloggs, 23 Anytown Street, Anytown
>
> On the following pages it says:
>
> Briggs & Co                (   )                                 Page
>   1
>
> I want it to say is:
>
> Briggs & Co       (   )             23 Anytown Street, Anytown      ( 
>   )         Page 1
>
> Briggs & Co       (   )             23 Anytown Street, Anytown      ( 
>   )         Page 2

etc

At the moment I have to type the address in the header of each new section (there are nine sections!). I need a macro or hyperlink or something which will pick up the address on the front page and automatically insert it in the centre section of the header on the following pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to accomplish this, but I think that the easiest is through Document Properties.

In your document, go to File -> Properties.  In your case, I'd probably create a new Custom Property.  Here, I've called it "Address", given it the type "text", and entered in the address of 23 Anytown Street, Anytown.  Click OK when you've completed this.
[image]

Back in your document, place the cursor where you'd like this text to appear.  Then go to Insert -> Field, select "Document Information" in the left list, then "DocProperty" in the right list, and finally enter (with quotes!) "Address" below, and click OK.  Repeat this anywhere that you want the address to appear.
[image]